# How to add Typescript definitions to Express req & res

Tags: node.js, express, typescript

I have a set of controller functions for my REST API and I'm getting lots of the following

```
error TS7006: Parameter 'req' implicitly has an 'any' type.
```

Likewise for `res`.  I've been playing around with typeings etc. but with no success. For example the `Request` type parameter below does NOT work.

Here is an example of the controller files. The reference path is correct.

```
/// <reference path="../../../typings/tsd.d.ts" />    
/* globals require */    
"use strict";    
exports.test = (req : Request, res) => {
```

I tried adding `import * as express from "express";` into the file - I don't need it normally as these functions are exported and use by index.js which actually implements the routing.

And this is tsd.d.ts

```
/// <reference path="requirejs/require.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="express/express.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="mime/mime.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="node/node.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="serve-static/serve-static.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="bluebird/bluebird.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="mongoose/mongoose.d.ts" />
```

Comment: have you tried `exports.test = (req: express.Request, res)...`?

Comment: Thanks - that seems to help, except that it requires me to put `import * as express from "express";` in my controllers even though I don't use them in my code

Comment: how about `...req: Express.Request..` (uppercase E, as it is in the tsd)?

Comment: No, that does not seem to work. Thanks for what did work though

Answer (score 91):

You can use ES6 style named imports to import only the interfaces you need, rather than `import * as express from 'express'` which would include express itself.

First, make sure you have installed the type definitions for express (`npm install -D @types/express`).

Example:

```
// middleware/authCheck.ts
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';

export const authCheckMiddleware = (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  ...
};

// server.ts
import { authCheckMiddleware } from './middleware/authCheck';
app.use('/api', authCheckMiddleware);
```

Currently using TypeScript 2.3.4 and @types/express 4.0.36.

Comment: how would you do this using CommonJS syntax

Answer (score 41):

It can be daunting to type the arguments every time you need to write middleware functions so you can just type the whole function directly too.

```
npm i @types/express --save-dev ("@types/express": "^4.17.0")
```

After installing typings..

```
// This can be shortened..
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';
export const myMiddleware = (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  ...
};

// to this..
import { RequestHandler } from 'express';
export const myMiddleware: RequestHandler = (req, res, next) => {
  ...
};

// or in case it handles the error object
import { ErrorRequestHandler } from 'express';
export const myMiddleware: ErrorRequestHandler = (err, req, res, next) => {
  ...
};
```

Comment: I am using this approach and it is needed to import `{ Request, Response }` in every file that uses it, does not have a way of importing it once and making it available to the entire application?

Answer (score 18):

What I've found is that you can leverage TypeScript generics very effectively to create a wrapper around the Express `Request` type.

You can declare something that looks similar to this in an interfaces file/folder:

```
import { NextFunction, Request, Response } from 'express';

type TypedRequest<
  ReqBody = Record<string, unknown>,
  QueryString = Record<string, unknown>
> = Request<
  Record<string, unknown>,
  Record<string, unknown>,
  Partial<ReqBody>,
  Partial<QueryString>
>;

export type ExpressMiddleware<
  ReqBody = Record<string, unknown>,
  Res = Record<string, unknown>,
  QueryString = Record<string, unknown>
> = (
  req: TypedRequest<ReqBody, QueryString>,
  res: Response<Res>,
  next: NextFunction
) => Promise<void> | void;
```

`TypedRequest` is effectively a wrapper around Express' `Request` interface, and populates it with the generics that you pass it, but are also optional (note `Record<string, unknown>`. It then also applies a `Partial` around each of the generics (you probably want to make this a `DeepPartial` instead)

`ExpressMiddleware` takes in 3 optional generics `ReqBody` `Res` and `QueryString`. These are used to construct a function signature that resembles what middlewares/controllers should look like.

The above then allows you to strongly type & consume as follows:

```
import { ExpressMiddleware } from '../interfaces/ExpressMiddleware';

type Req = { email: string; password: string };

type Res = { message: string };

export const signupUser: ExpressMiddleware<Req, Res> = async (req, res) => {
  /* strongly typed `req.body`. yay autocomplete  */
  res.json({ message: 'you have signed up' }) // strongly typed response obj
};
```

I hope this helps someone. It's made a massive difference to my Express experience.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to do this is like so.

// create some shared types in your project

```
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';
export type MiddlewareFn = (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => void;
```

// then use the above types:

```
import {MiddlewareFn} from './my-types.d.ts'

router.get('/foo', <MiddlewareFn>function (req, res, next) {

   // ....
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Rather than installing types(`@types/express`) you should also define request parameters. Since every parameter is string, interface should base on  dictionary.

Here is an inline route handler:

```
interface GetParams {
  [key: string]: string
  paramName: string
}

router.get<GetParams>('/:paramName', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Parameter is ' + req.params.paramName)
})
```

Comment: it works, but it's so wrong. `paramName` is string or undefined... crap api and types from express side

Answer (score 1):

The simplest method is to use RequestHandler in express.

```
import { RequestHandler } from "express";

export const yourController: RequestHandler = (req, res , next)=>{
    res.send({})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
req: Express.Request
res: Express.Response
```

Comment: Please consider that you can also extend from the Express built-in type and interfaces for having more flexibility