# Typescript 2.2 Express req, res implicitly any

Tags: node.js, express, typescript

I'm struggeling a bit with adding types to a node/express project.

I'm using TypeScript 2.2 and express 4.x and I've installed types through npm:

`npm install --save-dev @types/express`

```js
import * as express from "express"

const app: express.Application = express()

app.get("/hello", (req, res) => {
  res.send("world")
})
```

This gives me:

```
src/app.ts(33,22): error TS7006: Parameter 'req' implicitly has an 'any' type.
src/app.ts(33,27): error TS7006: Parameter 'res' implicitly has an 'any' type.
```

I'm trying to avoid having to do this for all request handlers:

```
(req: express.Request, res: express.Response) => {}
```

In my mind it should able to infer those. Am I wrong? Is that not possible?

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "typeRoots": ["src/types", "node_modules/@types"]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ]
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You could change `noImplicitAny` to false, or change each of your routes. You can't have it both ways

Comment: I disagree with Varedis and can confirm that indeed the code you wrote should work and `(req, res)` should be typed automatically, since `app.get` has a type. if you use vscode (or any other editor that handels typescript good enough), try to do 'go to definition` on `express.Application`. The only thing I can think of is that somehow you don't get the types from `node_modules/@types`. Also try running typescript with `--traceResolution` flag and see from where the express types actually come.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add Typescript definitions to Express req & res](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34508081/how-to-add-typescript-definitions-to-express-req-res)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The express library's get method is too heavily overloaded (see here for demo https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/14cfa9f41c2835fcd22e7243a32b25253c310dee/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts#L25-L40)

```
interface RequestHandler {
    (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction): any;
}

interface ErrorRequestHandler {
    (err: any, req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction): any;
}

type PathParams = string | RegExp | (string | RegExp)[];

type RequestHandlerParams = RequestHandler | ErrorRequestHandler | (RequestHandler | ErrorRequestHandler)[];

interface IRouterMatcher<T> {
    (path: PathParams, ...handlers: RequestHandler[]): T;
    (path: PathParams, ...handlers: RequestHandlerParams[]): T;
}
```

The `RequestHandlerParams` is making it impossible to be reliably sure about what `req` and `res` have. Suggestion: just annotate it for now

Answer (score 9):

Try adding `Express` type

```
import {Express} from 'express'
var express = require('express')

const app:Express = express();

app.get('/test', (req, res) => {
  res.send({ message: 'Welcome to Express!' });
});
```

Comment: For me it already disappeared when I use 'import * as express from 'express';' instead of require.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve it by grabbing args types directly

```
import type { RequestHandler } from "express";

type ArgumentTypes<T> = T extends (...args: infer P) => any ? P : never;

type RequestHandlerArgs = ArgumentTypes<RequestHandler>;

app.use((...args: RequestHandlerArgs) => {
  const [req, res, next] = args;
  // ...
});
```