# IntelliJ unresolved error handler function of Express library

Tags: node.js, express, intellij-idea

My IntelliJ resolved the wrong type of parameter of the Express error handler function. I install @type/express but no luck
[image]
Do you have any idea to solve it?

Comment: doesn't work in VSCode as well - parameter types are inferred as any. The problem is that the library definitions make it impossible to be reliably sure what types are there.See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42560168/typescript-2-2-express-req-res-implicitly-any for more info.
You can try specifying the types explicitly using the JSDoc annotations

Answer (score 0):

It's not an error just that the "use" function is too overloaded, if it bothers you you can replace it with the following code

```js
// TODO: ERROR HANDLER!
app.use(errorHandler);

function errorHandler (err, req, res, next) {
  console.error(err);
  res.status(err.status || 500).send(err.stack);
}
```